# Dynamic number of fields in database at runtime

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, jpa

I am currently developing a **spring boot** application with a **database** for patient data. I would really like to use spring's **JPA** as I am familiar with it but there is a problem I have with no satisfying solution for.

The problem is, we have several parameters to be store in DB. But in the future, these parameters might change and I would have to add new parameters and persist them in my DB.
Unfortunately, I am not the person entering all the data by hand but just the person writing the application.

Is there any way to dynamically add a column on runtime and save into the database.

If not, I was thinking about another approach where instead of saving entries as follows:

```
| PatientID | param1 | param2 | param3 | ... |
```

I would save them like this:

```
| PatientID | ParameterType | Value | Date     |
| 1         | param1        | 10    | 1.1.2021 |
| 1         | param2        | 15    | 1.2.2021 |
...
```

I would really appreciate any input you can give me, even completely different approaches

Comment: You can just have a column "additionalData" which stores e.g. a json document of all the additional data that does not fit into the pre-defined columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you store document instead of entity. For that you can use [Spring-data-couchbase](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-couchbase) because we don't know the data structure.

You can explore [SQL vs noSQL](https://circleci.com/blog/SQL-vs-NoSQL-databases/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=sem&utm_campaign=sem-google-dg--emea-en-dsa-maxConv-auth-brand&utm_term=g_b-_c__dsa_&utm_content=&gclid=CjwKCAjwiY6MBhBqEiwARFSCPg_XNHyeU05UCI7QsjMbDZWmXGq5j60aIdAE2jh15ROym4zoff4t5xoCa6wQAvD_BwE)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I completely forgot about NoSQL approaches. This is pretty much exactly what I need.